# Why are there no computers in Saajan's office?

Tags: analysis, lunchbox

In the Bollywood movie, *The Lunchbox*, why are there no computers in Saajan's (Irrfan Khan) office?

I was surprised to see that all the employees were doing their work manually where they all were accountants as shown in the film. (There were calculators shown). The story is of present time. So there can not be a problem of computers not been invented.

Nowadays, accounting job (actually any job) requires computers. Was it a mistake or deliberately shown like this? If deliberately shown, what could be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 3):

It's not unusual in India, for an office to not have computers.
Many offices especially non-private ones still use manual techniques.
Reason is that most employees are working since a long time and are not used to computers.
They prefer manual methods which they are more proficient in.
Besides, we don't know whether we saw the whole office in Lunchbox.
There might be more rooms, with computers.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what is already said by Ankit, *The Lunchbox* was a low budget movie. Not having computers may be part of being "low-budget".